# mysql calculate seconds between two date/times for each day

Tags: mysql

I have this table but I am helpless how to calculate seconds for each separate day from this table:

```
id  from            to
---------------------------------------------------
1   2013-01-31 23:50:00 2013-02-02 09:00:00
2   2013-02-05 11:21:12 2013-02-08 01:01:01
3   2013-02-08 17:33:44 2013-02-08 18:22:55
4   2013-02-12 01:40:12 2013-02-12 02:00:59
5   2013-02-28 01:40:12 2013-03-02 02:00:59
```

Now I need to gain number of seconds for each day in february between from and to.
so for 1st Feb - x seconds, 2nd Feb - y seconds, 3rd Feb - 0 seconds, etc. Any idea how should I do it? Many thanks.

Comment: @dom: The OP wants the results grouped by day.

Comment: For an SQL query to return the results you want, you must join your table with a column that contains the dates for which you wish to have results. MySQL does not natively provide any means of generating all dates (or even integers) within a given interval, so you must either materialise such a table in your application layer, or else store a program within MySQL that generates such a temporary table. If doing the latter, you may as well store a program within MySQL that builds your desired resultset more directly. This all suggests that MySQL may not be the best tool for this problem.

Comment: Slight variation to give number of sections per fromDate: select fromDate, sum(seconds)
from
(
    SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `from`, `to`) as seconds, date(`from`) as fromDate
    from t1
) t2
group by fromDate; http://rextester.com/QEPL38222

Answer (score 80):

Use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) in MySQL:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,from,to);
```

Example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-11 00:00:00'); -- 864000
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-11 00:00:00'); -- 14400
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-11 00:00:00'); -- 240
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-11 00:00:00'); -- 10
```

Comment: The OP wants the results grouped by day.